# Comma or colon?

Tags: commas, colons

Hello how can I determine if something is a parenthetical phrase?

For example:

> That was a new consideration: whole-body ectothermy in a variety of bees.

Is this correct? Or would a comma work better?

Answer (score 1):

> That was a new consideration: whole-body ectothermy in a variety of bees.

One of the [common uses of colons](https://writingcenter.unc.edu/tips-and-tools/semi-colons-colons-and-dashes/) explained in the link is

> 1. To announce, introduce, or direct attention to a list, a noun or noun phrase, a quotation, or an example/explanation.

> My roommate gave me the things I needed most: companionship and quiet.

The cited example is similar to OP's.

The line between a parenthetical expression and an expression explaining the introductory clause can be fine.  I would usually gauge the weight of the expression; if it's deemed important, I use a colon.  Let's look at the *roommate* example.

*companionship and quiet* elaborates the introductory clause and is seen to be substantial.  The colon is hence appropriate.

In OP's example, *whole-body ectothermy in a variety of bees* is similarly seen to be substantial enough to warrant the use of the colon; the introductory clause alone

> That was a new consideration.

does not express sufficiently the original idea.

Answer (score 0):

Appositives are a type of parenthesis.
Because it comes at the end of the sentence, it is a *Climactic Appositive*, and these are usually *Emphatic* (for which a comma is too weak).
If the Appositive is short, you can use a dash, but yours is rather long, so a colon is appropriate
(it starts a list of one long item - a *Formal Appositive*).